# vb.net insert Code runs twice?

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, sql-insert

I have a aspx form in vs2012(vb.net) where an incident is created and after inserting the records into the table it passes the newly created ID into second table where it is the Foreign Key. However the insert code runs twice and creates two entries in the second table. I tried to pass the ID into a function and exiting the function but that did not work either. Any idea?

I do not want duplicate entry for Incident ID in the second table so I am trying to insert the Incident ID into the second table so then I can update that second table.

```
    Protected Sub btnCreateIncident_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateIncident.Click
    Try
        InciDS.InsertParameters("PatronID").DefaultValue = strPID
        InciDS.InsertParameters("PatronName").DefaultValue = PatName
        InciDS.InsertParameters("Inci_type").DefaultValue = ddInciCatList.SelectedItem.Text.Trim()
        InciDS.InsertParameters("Inci_date").DefaultValue = txtDate.Text.Trim()
        InciDS.InsertParameters("Inci_time").DefaultValue = ddEventHour.SelectedItem.Text.Trim() + ":" + ddEventMin.SelectedItem.Text.Trim()
        InciDS.InsertParameters("Active").DefaultValue = "True"
        InciDS.InsertParameters("LocDescription").DefaultValue = LocDesc.Text.Trim()
        InciDS.InsertParameters("Location").DefaultValue = ddLocation.SelectedItem.Text.Trim()
        InciDS.InsertParameters("Library").DefaultValue = ddBldg.SelectedItem.Text.Trim()
        InciDS.InsertParameters("Description").DefaultValue = txtInciDesc.Content
        InciDS.InsertParameters("Action_Taken").DefaultValue = txtActionTaken.Content
        InciDS.InsertParameters("Involved_patrons").DefaultValue = txtPatronDesc.Content
        InciDS.InsertParameters("FollowUp").DefaultValue = txtFollowUp.Content
        InciDS.InsertParameters("Created_By").DefaultValue = strCreatedBy.Text.Trim()
        InciDS.Insert()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    PassParameters = strPID
    PassParameters = PassParameters + "&value2=" + PatName
    PassParameters = PassParameters + "&value3=" + NewID

    Response.Redirect("~/IntermediatePage.aspx?value1=" & PassParameters, False)

End Sub

Protected Sub InciDS_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles InciDS.Inserted
    'get the newly id of the newly created incident
    NewID = e.Command.Parameters("@Inci_ID").Value.ToString
    PoliceDS.InsertParameters("IncidentID").DefaultValue = NewID
    PoliceDS.Insert()
    'Newid = Convert.ToInt16(e.Command.Parameters("@Inci_ID").Value)
End Sub
```